# Decode querystring in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

I use PagingControl of DNN in my module. when mode is not postback i had this problem.
url is: `.../DNNArticle/list/reftabid/97?tag=تگ`

whn page is change. url is: `...DNNArticle/list/reftabid/97/currentpage/3?tag=ØªÚ¯`

i need to get tag value for filtering my query. but when page is change i can't do it.
i use this code to get value of tag parameter:

```
 System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection qscoll = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Request.QueryString.ToString()));
 foreach (string skey in qscoll.AllKeys){
      if (skey.ToLower() == "tag"){
         taganme = qscoll[skey];
         taganme = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(taganme);                         
      }
 }
```

it happen when tag value is persian word. in english words i have no problem

Comment: Weird, clearly an encoding problem... Somewhere along the processing it is reading it in an encoding and writing in another. You could work around it by using base64 to encode the string before putting it on the URL, and then after the postback do the reverse.. An ugly kludge but it would work.

Comment: i coulden't access to url before postback